# Android Apps GUI - is it possible to nest LinearLayout?

Tags: android, nested, android-linearlayout

I'm doing some experimentation with Android Apps Studio, specifically the portion that allows the GUI to be designed. I am wondering if it is possible to nest LinearLayouts? What I am trying to do is as follows, reading vertically from the top:
a blank panel, to fill the width of the screen (contents TBD);
a map;
then a horizontal pane, with a button and an edit field next to each other, with the button only taking up enough space to print the text upon it - the remainder of the space being taken up by the edit box.

I've put a weight in the vertical panels, to prevent the map element taking up all the screen.

It is this last pane that is causing problems; when I run the test GUI, it shows the button and edit box at the top of the screen, next to each other, with nothing below. 
My code is below; can anyone help please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".05"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="Test GUI"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"/>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".85"
    tools:context=".TestGUI" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#004D79"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>
    <Button android:text="Test"
        android:id="@+id/testButton"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="80dp">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You forgot to set the `layout_height` and `layout_weight` appropriately on the inner `<LinearLayout>`.

Comment: Thanks - I feel such an idiot. Backside suitable self-kicked.